Pgfplot:Confused about quiver plots
I am trying to plot slope field for: y'=.5*sin(x*pi/2)*sqrt(y+7)
I checked some examples but I am still confused. I tried the below MWE, obviously I did something wrong:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      view     = {0}{90},
      domain   = -3:3,
      y domain = -3:3,
      samples  = 30,
      xmin     = -3,
      xmax     = 3,
      ymax     = 3
    ]
    \addplot3 [quiver={u={1}, v={0.5*sqrt(y+7)*rad(sin(x*pi/2))}, scale arrows=0.075,
               }] (x,y,0);
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Shouldn't rad(sin(x*pi/2)) be sin(deg(x*pi/2))? Also, you need to specify a z-range

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\newcommand{\myFunction}{.5*sin(deg(x*pi/2))*sqrt(y+7)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view      = {0}{90}
    ,domain   = -3:3
    ,y domain = -3:3
    ,xmin     = -3
    ,xmax     = 3
    ,ymax     = 3
    ,zmin     = -1
    ,zmax     = 1
]
\addplot3[
    gray
    ,quiver={
        u={1/(sqrt(1+(\myFunction)^2))}
        ,v={(\myFunction)/(sqrt(1+(\myFunction)^2))}
        ,scale arrows=0.2
    }
] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


